# $ \widehat{\alpha} : {\pi}_1 (X, x_0) \longrightarrow {\pi}_1 (X, x_1) $ is well defined?

Tags: algebraic-topology, fundamental-groups

Definition: Let $X$ be a topological space and $ \alpha : I \longrightarrow X $ a path from $x_0$ to $x_1$.  We define a map

$ \widehat{\alpha} : {\pi}_1 (X, x_0) \longrightarrow {\pi}_1 (X, x_1) $

by the eqution:

$ \widehat{\alpha}([f]):= [\bar{\alpha}]*[f]*[\alpha] $.

I want to show that this map is well defined. by definition I have to show that

If $ [f], [f^´] \in {\pi}_1 (X, x_0) $ such that $  [f] = [f^´] $, then $  \widehat{\alpha}([f]) = \widehat{\alpha}([f^´]) $

to do this, I know that it is enough to prove that

$ f \; {\simeq}_p \; f^´ $ imply $  \widehat{\alpha}([f]) \; {\simeq}_p \;\widehat{\alpha}([f^´]) $.

but I do not know how to proceed from that point!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need only to check that $\ast$ is well-defined on the homotopy classes. Munkres does it like this:

First, if $f$ is a path from $x$ to $y$ and $g$ is a path from $y$ to $z$, define $\ast$ by

$(f\ast g)(s):=h(s)=\begin{cases} 
      f(2s) & 0\le s\le  1/2 \\
      g(2s-1)& 1/2\leq s\leq 1 \\ 
   \end{cases}$

Now, define an operation, also denoted $\ast$, on the homotopy classes, $[f]\ast[g]= [f\ast g].$

To show that $\ast$ is well-defined, let $F$ be a path homotopy between $f$ and $f'$, and $G$ a path homotopy between $g$ and $g'$.

Then, check that there is a path homotopy between $f\ast g$ and $f'\ast g'$ given by

$H(s,t)=\begin{cases} 
      F(2s,t) & 0\le s\le  1/2 \\
      G(2s-1,t)& 1/2\leq s\leq 1 \\ 
   \end{cases}.$

Comment: Great idea! It's simple but I did not think it would be useful here. how is $ f \;{\simeq}_p \; f^´ $ and $ \alpha \; {\simeq}_p \; \alpha $ then, by what you described above we will have $ f * \alpha \;\; {\simeq}_p \;\; f^´ *\alpha  $.

Comment: Still as $ \widehat{\alpha} \;\; {\simeq}_p \;\; \widehat{\alpha}  $ we get
$ \widehat{\alpha} * f * \alpha \;\; {\simeq}_p \;\; \widehat{\alpha} * f^´ *\alpha $ and, so we will have $  \widehat{\alpha}([f]) \; {\simeq}_p \; \widehat{\alpha}([f^´]) $. Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

It is useful to have the algebraic, abstract,  formulation of this "change of base point",  which is actually a  result on groupoids (e.g. 6.3.1 and 6.3.2 of [Topology and Groupoids](http://groupoids.org.uk/topgpds.html)) applied to the fundamental groupoid $\pi_1(X)$ of a topological space $X$.

There is a not too well known formulation which links this result  with another idea, that of **crossed module**.

Let $G$ be a groupoid with object set $X$, The object group of $G$ at an object $x$ is written $G(x)$. Then there is a groupoid $Aut(G)$ with object set $X$ and where $$Aut(G)(x,y)= Iso(G(x),G(y)), $$
the set of isomorphisms $G(x) \to G(y)$.

There is a morphism of groupoids
$$\chi:G \to Aut(G) $$
which sends $a:x \to y$ to the "change of base" conjugation $G(x) \to G(y)$. (Some care is needed with conventions for conjugation and composition of morphisms to get $\chi$ to be a morphism rather than an antimorphism.)

The rules that $\chi$  satisfies are just like the "crossed module"  rules given in  this book, [Nonabelian Algebraic Topology](http://grou[oids.org.uk/nonab-a-t.html), and indeed if  $G$  is a group then $\chi$  is a standard example of a crossed module. But I have seen few uses of the generalisation, and that is why I am advertising it here.

Comment: Great answer, I did not think that way. Thank you very much for the book that you recommended. I will make good use of it.